# How to repeat the same value in all the cells of the column using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want a value to repeat itself in all the cells of the columns. I want to use Arrayformula for doing that. How can i do?

[image: The Value of WM should be repeated all the cells of the coloumn]

Answer (score 0):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX({"WM Number"; SUBSTITUTE(ROW(A3:A)^0, 0, )&"917893656466"})
```

[image]